# How to add to an NSSet using Core Data in Swift 5

Tags: swift, core-data

So I'm practicing a little more with core data after finishing a course. So I am still a little new to it. So I Have 3 entities named Pokemon, Type & Ability. So a Pokemon can have many types like Fire,Water,Flying and so on. Type can also have multiple Pokemon that are Fire,Water,Flying and so on. Same goes for the Ability, so I made a many-to-many relationship. Here is how it looks like.

[image]

I am parsing some JSON form an api and trying to save it into core data. Now here is where I am having a bit of trouble. This is how my code looks and it just basically parse the JSON.

```
struct Service {
static let shared = Service()

func downloadPokemonsFromServer(completion: @escaping ()->()) {
    let urlString = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=9"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("Unable to fetch pokemon", err)
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }
        let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateContext.parent = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

        do {
            let pokemonJSON = try decoder.decode(PokemonsJSON.self, from: data)
            pokemonJSON.pokemons.forEach { (JSONPokemon) in
               let pokemon = Pokemon(context: privateContext)
                pokemon.name = JSONPokemon.name
                pokemon.url = JSONPokemon.detailUrl

                //Would want to set pokemon types here but
                //When i call fetchMoreDetails(pokemon:,urlString:,completion:)
                //The pokemon is always nil inside fetchMoreDetails
            }

            try privateContext.save()
            try privateContext.parent?.save()
            completion()
        } catch let err {
            print("Unable to decode PokemonJSON. Error: ",err)
            completion()
        }


    }.resume()
}

func fetchMoreDetails(pokemon: Pokemon, urlString: String, completion: @escaping ()->()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }


    let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateContext.parent = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("Unable to get more details for pokemon", err)
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }


        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

        do {
            let pokemonDetailJSON = try decoder.decode(PokemonDetailJSON.self, from: data)
            pokemonDetailJSON.types.forEach { (nestedType) in
                let type = Type(context: privateContext)
                type.name = nestedType.type.name

                //How do I add type to pokemon.types this does work
                //pokemon.types?.adding(type)

            }

            try privateContext.save()
            try privateContext.parent?.save()

            completion()

        } catch let err {
            print("Unable to decode pokemon more details", err)
            completion()
        }

    }.resume()
}
}
```

I am able to parse everything fine and all but I just can't seem to add a new type to pokemons.types. I have look on stack overflow but most of the solutions seem to be in Objective C.

This is how my ViewController looks like and I am also using a NSFetchResultController.

```
class PokemonTableVC: UITableViewController {

lazy var pokemonController: NSFetchedResultsController<Pokemon> = {
    let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Pokemon> = Pokemon.fetchRequest()
    let nameSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [nameSort]

    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    controller.delegate = self
    return controller
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
    tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Delete", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(handleDelete))

    try? pokemonController.performFetch()
}

@objc func handleDelete() {
    print("Deleting")
    let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext

    guard let pokemons = pokemonController.fetchedObjects else { return }
    pokemons.forEach { (pokemon) in
        context.delete(pokemon)
    }

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch let err {
        print("Unable to save data", err)
    }
}

@objc func handleRefresh() {
    print("DDDDD")
    Service.shared.downloadPokemonsFromServer {
        self.pokemonController.fetchedObjects?.forEach({ (pokemon) in
            print(pokemon.name)
           Service.shared.fetchMoreDetails(pokemon: pokemon, urlString: pokemon.url ?? "") {
                print(pokemon.abilities?.count)

            }
        })
    }
    tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}

}
```

I can provide my other structs if needed. But basically I am trying to add a type to pokemon.types would also like to add fetchMoreDetails when I fetch pokemons where I put the comment at. Would
really appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a relationship to an entity Xcode creates methods for getting and setting values for that relationship using a pre-defined naming standard. So you should have some methods in your Pokemon class for setting Type instances (and code completion should be able to help here):

```
addToTypes(value:) // single object
addToTypes(values:) //set of objects
```

So in your code it should be

```
pokemon.addToTypes(value: type)
```

You also have the same methods on Type for the opposite direction

Comment: WOW. I was using this instead pokemon.types?.adding(). Thanks.